# Stack ExitFailure 1

Tags: haskell, haddock

I've been trying to run `stack install hsdev --stack-yaml ./Documents/hsdev.yaml`, where `hsdev.yaml` contains

```
packages: []
resolver: lts-13.29
extra-deps:
- hsdev-0.3.3.4
- hdocs-0.5.3.2
- haddock-api-2.22.0
- network-3.0.1.1
```

This returns the error

```
--  While building package haddock-api-2.22.0 using:
      /home/hello/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.5 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1 build --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I have already tried `haddock-api-2.21.0`, which results in the same error. I have also tried running `stack install haddock-api`.
I am on Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon, if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I was missing something.
`sudo apt-get install libtinfo-dev` fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks so much! This fixed the same issue for me on Ubuntu on WSL.

Answer (score 0):

On a fresh install of Ubuntu Bionic.

Had a similar error while trying to install Haskell:

```
git clone https://github.com/haskell/haskell-ide-engine --recursive

cd haskell-ide-engine

stack install
```

Your fix solved the problem - thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! That is not an answer to any question, please delete.