# How to diagnose ExitFailure 1 in a stack build?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

When trying to build a library depending on alsa-core:

```
$ stack --nix build
alsa-core                        > configure
alsa-core                        > Configuring alsa-core-0.5.0.1...
alsa-core                        > Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.5: The program 'pkg-config' version
alsa-core                        > >=0.9.0 is required but it could not be found.
alsa-core                        > 
async                            > configure
async                            > Configuring async-2.2.2...
async                            > build
async                            > Preprocessing library for async-2.2.2..
async                            > Building library for async-2.2.2..
async                            > [1 of 1] Compiling Control.Concurrent.Async
async                            > copy/register
async                            > Installing library in /home/brandon/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-nix/79951401c5830a0f21032e12e8be34b2fa621f0af660dd35b1ab0ad985f6ab0e/8.6.5/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.6.5/async-2.2.2-EbxQ7tk0OFk9dJNMtaidSf
async                            > Registering library for async-2.2.2..

--  While building package alsa-core-0.5.0.1 using:
      /home/brandon/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.5 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-2.4.0.1 configure --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/home/brandon/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-nix/79951401c5830a0f21032e12e8be34b2fa621f0af660dd35b1ab0ad985f6ab0e/8.6.5/pkgdb --libdir=/home/brandon/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-nix/79951401c5830a0f21032e12e8be34b2fa621f0af660dd35b1ab0ad985f6ab0e/8.6.5/lib --bindir=/home/brandon/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-nix/79951401c5830a0f21032e12e8be34b2fa621f0af660dd35b1ab0ad985f6ab0e/8.6.5/bin --datadir=/home/brandon/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-nix/79951401c5830a0f21032e12e8be34b2fa621f0af660dd35b1ab0ad985f6ab0e/8.6.5/share --libexecdir=/home/brandon/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-nix/79951401c5830a0f21032e12e8be34b2fa621f0af660dd35b1ab0ad985f6ab0e/8.6.5/libexec --sysconfdir=/home/brandon/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-nix/79951401c5830a0f21032e12e8be34b2fa621f0af660dd35b1ab0ad985f6ab0e/8.6.5/etc --docdir=/home/brandon/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-nix/79951401c5830a0f21032e12e8be34b2fa621f0af660dd35b1ab0ad985f6ab0e/8.6.5/doc/alsa-core-0.5.0.1 --htmldir=/home/brandon/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-nix/79951401c5830a0f21032e12e8be34b2fa621f0af660dd35b1ab0ad985f6ab0e/8.6.5/doc/alsa-core-0.5.0.1 --haddockdir=/home/brandon/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-nix/79951401c5830a0f21032e12e8be34b2fa621f0af660dd35b1ab0ad985f6ab0e/8.6.5/doc/alsa-core-0.5.0.1 --dependency=base=base-4.12.0.0 --dependency=extensible-exceptions=extensible-exceptions-0.1.1.4-KI0dG6kQM84KnSzvR2Yb0 -fpkgconfig --extra-include-dirs=/nix/store/hg3na12737n7wws1kndxvs95ai88fgn8-ghc-8.6.5/include --extra-include-dirs=/nix/store/06q8j7z84zqjzcijvz90i4v7j5mfk4jl-git-2.23.1/include --extra-include-dirs=/nix/store/291ldi6fqsbmkbvbs8is4mcg3jb64ld4-gcc-wrapper-8.3.0/include --extra-include-dirs=/nix/store/a7qdsbw0fnk4rdbi50m65i26202wwr71-gmp-6.1.2-dev/include --extra-lib-dirs=/nix/store/hg3na12737n7wws1kndxvs95ai88fgn8-ghc-8.6.5/lib --extra-lib-dirs=/nix/store/06q8j7z84zqjzcijvz90i4v7j5mfk4jl-git-2.23.1/lib --extra-lib-dirs=/nix/store/291ldi6fqsbmkbvbs8is4mcg3jb64ld4-gcc-wrapper-8.3.0/lib --extra-lib-dirs=/nix/store/sisy13ic6giv9yn0fyl2n9cpm84xscvx-gmp-6.1.2/lib --exact-configuration --ghc-option=-fhide-source-paths
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Progress 2/94
```

Based on this [Stack ExitFailure 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609824/stack-exitfailure-1), it sounds as though a system library is probably missing, but is there any way to get better information displayed about which one? I tried passing `--verbose` to stack, but this didn't seem to add any (relevant) information.

Comment: I confirmed the missing system dep was alsaLib, as that was the most likely suspect.

Comment: unfortunately i'm still getting the error later with a different dependency (iwlib), and for that, i'm less sure about what is missing.

Comment: in the second case it seemed to be `wirelesstools`